# Efficiently collapse IEnumerable values together

Tags: c#, arrays

I'd like to 'collapse' the values in some `IEnumerable` together such that adjacent elements that are the same get collapsed to a single element.

I can't think of a better way to describe the problem other than an example:

The array [0,0,2,0,1,1,2,2,2,1,0,0,2,1,1,0,1,1,1]
Should become [0,2,0,1,2,1,0,2,1,0,1]

In my use case, this needs to happen in a critical loop and therefore must be as fast as possible. I could loop through the array and check each element against the previous, removing if it's a duplicate, but I'm hoping there's a faster way.

My use will only be for relatively short arrays (<100 elements) and only uses `int`, however a general purpose solutions would be appreciated.

EDIT: As pointed out below, the problem is fundamentally O(n) complexity, but I was hoping something linqy might beat my (probably clumsy) implementation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want a general-purpose solution, write an extension method:

This should do the job just fine:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> DistinctConsecutive<T>(this IEnumerable<T> sequence)
    => sequence.DistinctConsecutive(EqualityComparer<T>.Default);

public static IEnumerable<T> DistinctConsecutive<T>(this IEnumerable<T> sequence, IEqualityComparer<T> comparer)
{
    if (sequence == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(sequence));
    if (comparer == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(comparer));

    return DistinctConsecutiveImpl(sequence, comparer);
}

private static IEnumerable<T> DistinctConsecutiveImpl<T>(IEnumerable<T> sequence, IEqualityComparer<T> comparer)
{
    using (var enumerator = sequence.GetEnumerator())
    {
        if (!enumerator.MoveNext())
            yield break;

        var lastValue = enumerator.Current;
        yield return lastValue;

        while (enumerator.MoveNext())
        {
            var value = enumerator.Current;
            if (comparer.Equals(lastValue, value))
                continue;

            yield return value;
            lastValue = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Or, the *lazier* approach:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> DistinctConsecutive<T>(this IEnumerable<T> sequence, IEqualityComparer<T> comparer = null)
{
    if (comparer == null)
        comparer = EqualityComparer<T>.Default;

    using (var enumerator = sequence.GetEnumerator())
    {
        if (!enumerator.MoveNext())
            yield break;

        var lastValue = enumerator.Current;
        yield return lastValue;

        while (enumerator.MoveNext())
        {
            var value = enumerator.Current;
            if (comparer.Equals(lastValue, value))
                continue;

            yield return value;
            lastValue = value;
        }
    }
}
```

If you need an optimized solution, throw out generics and use `==` instead of the `IEqualityComparer<T>`. And if this is still a bottleneck, do it with a plain old `for` loop.

Comment: Rather than a second overload you can just use `null` as the default value for the comparer.

Comment: @Servy that's what I actually did in the first revision of the answer, but I then changed my mind to get consistent with Linq.

Answer (score 4):

> I could loop through the array and check each element against the previous, removing if it's a duplicate, but I'm hoping there's a faster way.

Fundamentally there's never going to be a way that's faster algorithmically.  There can be subtle differences in implementations using that same algorithm, but that's the best that you can get.  There's no way to avoid checking each item, so the operation will be O(n) no matter what you do.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. I'll accept the answer below as it contains an implementation.

Comment: @JackCoiley So you didn't know how to loop through the collection and get the items that are different from the previous one?  The question implied that you already knew how to do that.

Comment: I already had a basic extension implementing it with a for loop. I was mainly saying thanks for pointing out the algorithm's complexity for future readers :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`ChunkBy` extension provided on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc138361.aspx). Then it's easy:

```
var src = new[]{0, 0, 2, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 0, 0, 2, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1};
var pruned = src.ChunkBy(x => x).Select(c => c.First());
```

Comment: I'm interested to see how this can be faster (or even equally fast) than looping over the collection once and comparing each value to the previous value. Doesn't this code loop over the entire collection and then loop over a reduced set afterwards?

Comment: @Stijn Well, from an algorithmic standpoint, that's exactly what it *is* doing.  It's likely to have a *bit* more overhead than doing so explicitly (as it needs to build a collection of the chunks, even though only the one previous value actually needs to be remembered).  If this is used in a tight, performance critical loop, that overhead could matter, or it could not; it'd need to be tested.